# Rails, model relationship child-parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I have a simple app and I have to describe the relationship student-parent as many-to-many where the following would work:

> current_user.parents
>
> current_user.children

Currently I have the following

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :parent_students
  has_many :students, through: :parent_students, class_name: "User"
  has_many :parents,  through: :parent_students, class_name: "User"
end

class ParentStudent < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :student, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "student_id"
    belongs_to :parent,  class_name: "User", foreign_key: "parent_id"
end

class CreateParentStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :parent_students do |t|
        t.references :student, index: true, references: :users
        t.references :parent,  index: true, references: :users

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Any idea how this would work? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

probably this can help, the declaration inside User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # as parent
    has_many: student_relations, foreign_key: :parent_id, class_name: "ParentStudent"
    has_many: students, through: :student_relations, source: :student
  # as student
    has_many: parent_relations, foreign_key: :student_id, class_name: "ParentStudent"
    has_many: parents, through: :parent_relations, source: :parent
end

class ParentStudent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student, foreign_key: "student_id", class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :parent,  foreign_key: "parent_id",  class_name: "User"
end
```